# Kotlin anonymous class this

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the sample code in this question([getWidth() and getHeight() of View returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0)).

It had the following code,

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                view.getHeight(); //height is ready
            }
        });
```

And I wrote it in Kotlin like this

```
image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener{
    image_view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener { this }
    Log.d("Should be called once", "Height = " + image_view.height + ", Width = " + image_view.width)
};
```

The result was,

```
11-22 19:18:33.319 4754-4754/loser.qrcode D/Should be called once: Height = 672, Width = 672
11-22 19:18:33.328 4754-4754/loser.qrcode D/Should be called once: Height = 672, Width = 672
```

So, it was called twice. That is, `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener` did not work. What should I use instead of `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that Kotlin is asumming `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener` will need a [SAM expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions). Then when you are passing `{ this }`, you are just creating another `OnGlobalLayoutListener`instance, here the equivalent:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        YourOuterClass.this;
    }
});
```

And this listener doesn't exist in the current listeners list

In order to solve this, you have to declare your `OnGlobalLayoutListener` as an object and not as a lamba, like this you can reference the correct "**this**" and remove the listener properly once is called.

```
image_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        image_view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        Log.d("Should be called once", "Height = " + image_view.height + ", Width = " + image_view.width)
    }
})
```